# Getting blank page while editing pages in djangocms

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-cms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRzg8.png)

I am getting blank page while editing pages in Django CMS, sometimes I am able to edit but some time getting then blank page.

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
        {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}
   </ul>
      {% render_block "js" %}
  </nav>
```

Comment: provide us more details.it(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRzg8.png) seems that your page is working but you are trying to open a popup  and that popup shows blank page.

Comment: yes some time pop up will show the option to edit and all, but some time am getting blank page

Comment: But what is the popup? Include some code & template markup.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.